# tomcat 8 not starting anymore after java 8 installation

Tags: eclipse, java-8, tomcat8

I've run into something strange. Basically I downloaded java 8 and configured, I believe correctly, Eclipse to use it - I'm on ubuntu by the way - and when I tried to restart Tomcat 8 it just won't start and I get an error saying that "Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start."
I'm not sure how to deal with this, so I thought I'd provide the [console output](http://pastebin.com/aWJCUVyS), maybe you guys can help me to figure out what's wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I managed to figure it out. What tricked me was that I didn't have to do this in WIndows, but somehow it's a necessary step in Ubuntu (12.04). You need to edit the tomcat server properties,and change the installed JDK from 7 to 8 (preferences - server - Runtime environment - edit), that did the trick.